# Two different projects with the same name and GitHub

Tags: xcode, git, github

I have two projects, one is in the **Documents / Android Studio / Project** folder, the other project is in the **Documents / XCode / Project** folder. That is, in both cases the folder is called "Project". I added the Android Studio project from the Android Studio to Github and successfully tested it. The versioning system works as it should. Next, I decided to add a project from Xcode to GitHub. I added a GitHub account in the Xcode settings. Xcode showed the projects available for my account. Next, I try to add a project to Github by clicking **Source Control - Create Git Repositories**. Xcode reports that all projects are already under the control of the versioning system. If I click **Source Control - Commit**, it looks like Xcode offers to commit for all project files to the same online repository called Project, which stores the project from Android Studio. I don’t understand what to do, because it is not recommended to rename the Xcode project. How to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new github repo at github (browser) by some other name. Then follow the instructions for pushing your project to it in the Terminal using the command line. Do not use Xcode for this or any other git related stuff.

Comment: I renamed Android Studio project's repository on the Github and used GitHub desktop to add XCode project to the Github. XCode creates local repository only.

Comment: Well, fine, but as I suggested in my answer, Xcode is just being silly and inflexible. There is no reason why the project name and the github repository name should match, so Xcode should not make assumptions like this.